# Showing that a linear functional is non-negative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite positive measure and $\psi$ a linear functional on $L^2(\mu)$ with norm $1$. Let us define:

$$\psi^*(g) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g\,d \mu - \psi(g).$$

It is easy to see that $\psi^*$ is a linear functional.

Here is where I am getting a bit stuck. How can I show that if $g(x)\ge 0$, then $\psi^*$ is non-negative.

P.S. $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} g \, d \mu \ge 0 \quad \forall g(x) \ge 0.$$

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What space is $\psi$ a linear functional on? Is there any relationship between $\psi$ and $\mu$?

Comment: @carmichael561 $\psi$ is a linear functional on $L^2(\mu)$.

Comment: Is $\mu$ a finite measure? Otherwise I don't see why $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\;d\mu$ should be defined for every $g\in L^2(\mu)$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes, $\mu$ is a finite measure. The actually definition of $\psi(g) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} fg d\mu$ for every $g \in L^2(\mu)$ for a uniquely determined $f$

Comment: You probably want $\psi$ to be a functional on $L^1$. It's not true on $L^2$. For instance, on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure take the functional $ g \mapsto \int f g$, where $|| f ||_{L^2} =1$ but $f>1$ on some interval.